# How do I add the remainder of '%' modulos to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good afternoon, I am creating a simple program that takes the start time of an "event" and adds the "duration" in minutes only. Then displays when the event will be over. So the problem that I am running in to is when my *minutes* goes past 60 it doesn't add 1 to *hours* (Because modulos prevents it from ever reaching 60)

Here is the code:

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))

end_mins = (dura + mins) % 60
end_hr = (hour % end_mins) 

if end_mins > 60:
    end_hr += 1


if end_mins < 10:
    print('{}:0{}'.format(end_hr, end_mins))
else:
    print('{}:{}'.format(end_hr, end_mins))
```

Input
Starting time (hours): 2
Starting time (minutes): 30
Event duration (minutes): 35

Output
End time: 2:05

The obvious answer is supposed to be 3:05.

How do I go about fixing this bug and improving this code? Thank you for taking the time to read this far. Have a great rest of your day!

Comment: One option would be to convert to minutes: `end = mins + hour * 60 + dura; end_mins = end % 60; end_hr = end // 60` You would have to deal with times that end past midnight.

Comment: "Because modulos prevents it from ever reaching 60" So... do the check *before* the modulus part? Or, use the value that *can* exceed 60 (i.e. `dura + mins`) for the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the end hour using:

```
 end_hr = (hour + (dura + mins) // 60)
```

Sample output:

```
 Starting time (hours): 1
 Starting time (minutes): 58  
 Event duration (minutes): 64
 3:02
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that you are checking if `end_mins>60` and this will not happen in this case since you are applying `%60`

So you must replace `if(end_mins>60)` by `if(dura+mins)>60`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this with `divmod`, which is a built-in function that returns the tuple of the result of integer division and the modulus.

```
hrs, mins = divmod(dura + mins, 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

just convert everything to minutes and then convert back into hours then minutes:

```py
total = hour * 60 + mins + dura

end_hr = int(total / 60)
end_mins = total % 60

if end_mins < 10:
    print('{}:0{}'.format(end_hr, end_mins))
else:
    print('{}:{}'.format(end_hr, end_mins))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
try:
    hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
    mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
    dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
except ValueError:
    print('You entered something that was not a number, please try again')

end_mins = dura + mins
end_hr = (hour % end_mins)
while end_mins > 60: # using while allows for times like 1000 minutes to work correctly
    end_hr += 1
    end_mins -= 60
while end_hr > 12: # am-pm switch
    end_hr -= 12


if end_mins < 10:
    print('{}:0{}'.format(end_hr, end_mins))
else:
    print('{}:{}'.format(end_hr, end_mins))
```

Sample output

```py
Starting time (hours): 2
Starting time (minutes): 30
Event duration (minutes): 120
4:30

Starting time (hours): 4
Starting time (minutes): 20
Event duration (minutes): 50
5:10

Starting time (hours): 11
Starting time (minutes): 50
Event duration (minutes): 20
12:10

Starting time (hours): 12
Starting time (minutes): 59
Event duration (minutes): 10
1:09
```